# Repeating values on a table view cells Error from API response

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a view (**lets call it View 1**) with a button on it. When the button is clicked I make a GET http request to my API. It sends back an array of objects.

Currently what I am trying to do is that when a user presses the button on **view 1** the response data is passed to **view 2** which is a ***tableView***. And then fill up the table view cells with the returned data.

I am passing the returned JSON response from view 1 to view 2 like this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BioView") as! BioTableViewController

                    vc.bioArray = parseJSON
                    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
```

**Where parseJSON contains the returned JSON response.**

In View 2 I have the following:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
       {

            return self.bioArray.count

       }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    if bioArray.count > 0 {

        let weatherSummary: AnyObject = bioArray[indexPath.row]
        for x in bioArray {
            if let id = x["employeeName"] as? String{
                cell.textLabel?.text = id
            }
          }
        }

    return cell
  }
```

**The Issue:**

The table view keeps repeating the last value in the returned JSON data. see below:

[image]

**My Question:**

*How can stop the value from repeating and show all the values from the response data and when I click on the a tableview cell it goes to another view and shows all the details related to the clicked on cell.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `for` loop(because of it, table view keeps repeating value I guess). `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will do the same for you. Just try the code below :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

        let weatherSummary: AnyObject = bioArray[indexPath.row]

            if let id = weatherSummary["employeeName"] as? String //Dont know the exact syntax.
            {
                cell.textLabel?.text = id
            }

    return cell
  }
```

And to get rid of `if bioArray.count > 0` condition you can do like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
   return self.bioArray.count ?? 0 //This will return 0 rows if bioArray is empty.
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped! Do you how can I show the details of table view cell clicked on a new view. Basically like a detailed view for each table view cell?

Comment: You can bind your cell with detail view using segue. Please accept my answer

Comment: So bind a cell to a detail view and pass data through a segue? Can you provide any link to an already existing example

Comment: Yes and then you can pass data using `prepareForSegue`. Dont have the link right now. You should google it